# Solve the issue Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I have received this email from google for the second time for the same app:

> Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section
>   4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement
>
> Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when
>   the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information.
>   We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android
>   advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy
>   requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must
>   provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the
>   Play Console, and from within the app.

At this point it's clear that I am doing something wrong. I have found many answers to this question online and I have made the following to solve the problem:

1. I have opened https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/ and I have generated a policy:

[image]

2. I have uploaded the HTML of the generated policy in my website and I have put the link in the Google Play Developer console:

[image]

3. I have added in my app a link to the policy which has the same URL as the one that I have put in the google play developer console. The link can be reached in this way:

.

```
//Set the click event for the privacy policy
        theView.findViewById(R.id.privacy_policy).setOnClickListener(
                l -> startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(PRIVACY_POLICY_URL))
                )
        );
```

I am wondering: what else should I do?

---

Even with those actions I have made, my app has been removed today. Look at my gradle file if it can be useful:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Should I add some text in the field `Personally identifiable information you collect` in the policy generator? I have left if blank

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

As your email indicates, your app seems to collect the `Google Analytics AdId`. If you use Firebase services in your app, Google Advertising collection is enabled by default.

If you don't want to provide a privacy policy, one simple way to solve this issue is to disable the collection of the Advertising ID. You can simply add this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#disable_advertising_id_collection

Comment: Does this addition stop the usage of AdMob as well? I have AdView with AdMob in my app to monetize

Comment: I see, if you want to use AdMob, this solution won't work as it depends on the AdId.